# Selecting a particular value from SQL DB and store it in a shell variable

Tags: sql, shell, unix

From a unix shell program, I need to connect to a SQL database using the sqlplus command's proper syntax.Then I need to select a particular value from one of the DB tables and store it in a variable that is to be used in the later half of the shell program. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need some interface like sqlite or perl to connect to database. 
example will be 
set myvar=`sqlite3 ex1 'select empid from empTable where empname='abc'`

or write perl program that will connect to Database  will return the expected result.
for example if perl script is myDataquery.pl ... then

myvar=`$bin/perl myDataquery.pl`

will return the value in myvar ... then you can use that.

Comment: instead of sqllite, can we use sqlplus? If so, it will be really helpful if you can share the syntax.